# WinForms: Проблема с поиском данных по различным параметрам из DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

В `DataGridView` есть таблица, взятая в БД из `MySQL`. Пользователь может делать поиск значений из колонок `"Тип транспорту"` и `"Тип харчування"`. Проблема заключается в том, что пользователь может сделать поиск лишь в колонке "Тип харчування", в то время как значения из первой не считываются. Заранее спасибо за помощь. Вот код:

```
dvSearch.RowFilter = "[Тип транспорту] LIKE '" + TransComboBox.Text + "'";
dvSearch.RowFilter = "[Тип харчування] LIKE '" + EatComboBox.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Оба условия записать в одной строке через оператор `AND`.

Comment: Я уже давал ссылку на [Expression Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0#expression-syntax). Смотрите там примеры. Хотя, конечно, описание там не очень и форматирование кривое.

Comment: это хотите получить? dvSearch.RowFilter = "[Тип транспорту] LIKE '" + TransComboBox.Text + "' AND [Тип харчування] LIKE '" + EatComboBox.Text + "'";

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо вам

Comment: @Konst а если я хочу, чтобы была возможность сделать поиск даже с пустым параметром? К примеру, если в EatComboBox ничего не записывать, а только в TransComboBox, то не выводит ничего, а нужно, чтобы выводились элементы, удовлетворяющие запросу в TransComboBox. Надо ли в таком случае делать какую-то проверку на пустое значение в EatComboBox?